# I have created React native app and build it as a standalone android apk file but I am unable to use it without connecting to same network

Tags: android, json, reactjs, react-native, json-server

I have created React native app with JSON server (use to transfer some data from my computer to my app) and build it as a standalone android apk file and installed it on my android device, but even after build it as a standalone apk file it can't work without connecting to the **same network** for fetching data from my JSON server.

Is there any way to use my app with the server running on my computer and without connecting to the same network?

or can I run the JSON server online somewhere else, of course, free of cost as I am a developer and I am just trying as a sack of my knowledge and use that link in my app for fetching data?

Thankx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like https://my-json-server.typicode.com/ to host the JSON file. Then you can access it remotely anywhere. Another alternative is https://jsonbin.io/

In case you need more help, you can refer [this article](https://medium.com/@royanimesh2211/create-a-free-fake-rest-api-with-json-server-running-on-the-internet-30a627c7c20d).